# How to access the resultset values using multi threads

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc

I have created below JDBC program to get the record from database

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@db-user-rw-a.qa.amazon.com:1100/MONEY";
String username = "amazon212313";
String password = "XXXXX";

System.out.println("Connecting database...");
Connection connection = null;
if (connection == null) 
{
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username,password);
        System.out.println("Database connected!");
        } 
    catch (Exception ex)
        {
        System.out.println("Database Connection Failed...!!!");
        System.out.println(ex);
        }
}

Statement statement=connection.createStatement();

ResultSet rs1=statement.executeQuery("select account_number,flag,flag2,flag3,flag4,flag5,flag6,flag7,amount from transaction_p2");

 ResultSetMetaData metadata = rs1.getMetaData();
 int columnCount = metadata.getColumnCount(); 
 System.out.println(columnCount);

 while(rs1.next())
 {
      // account_number in if condition

     if(rs1.getString(1).contains("2195281819521610731"))
     {
     System.out.println(rs1.getString(1));
     }
 }


connection.close();
```

I have more than 99000 records in data base and the above program is working fine but its taking huge time to retrieve the specific account number values. It's taking more than 20 minutes (Some times beyond that) to retrieve the value.

Is there any other way to speed up the search value in result set. Like creating 100 thread to search the specific account number if it found then It should return the value.

Also, there is possibly a duplicate account number in the database. All I want that I need multithreads to access the resultset and search the specific account number and return all the found account number as per if condition.

Share yours idea to achieve this task.

Updated the program with WHERE clause and observed below in console:

**Updated Code:**

```
  ResultSet rs1=statement.executeQuery("select account_number,flag,flag2,flag3,flag4,flag5,flag6,flag7,amount from transaction_p2 where account_number=2195281819521610731");
     ResultSetMetaData metadata = rs1.getMetaData();
     int columnCount = metadata.getColumnCount(); 
     System.out.println(columnCount);
     System.out.println(rs1.next()+"\t boolean value");

     while(rs1.next())
     {
          // account_number in if condition
         System.out.println(rs1.getString(1));
     }
```

**Output:**

```
Connecting database...
Database connected!
12
false    boolean value
```

If I used execute() instead of executeQuery() which is returning "TRUE" but not sure how can i get resultset details.

The above account number queried in db and got result.

[image]

Comment: Add a where clause to your SQL select query to only retrieve **the** row(s) that you're actually care about, instead of loading all the rows and filtering them. That's what a database is all about: being able to quickly get what you want be sending the appropriate queries.

Comment: @JB Nizet - I used where clause but the resultset had more than one column values so it returned false. (rs1.next) returned false. As I said I have multiple matching account number in result set. So the executeQuery is not working and its returning false. I used execute() method but its returning boolean value as true but not sure how can I get the values from resultset.

Comment: That doesn't happen because the resultset had more than one column values. It happened because your query returned no row at all, which means that your where clause wasn't the correct one, or that the rows you think the database contains don't actually exist.

Comment: I queried in sql lite it returned values but executeQuery () doesn't return. but If I use execute() then It return true but not sure how can I get those values.

Comment: If you want help, don't describe what you're doing in comments. Post the actual code you tried, and what your database table contains

Comment: You shouldn't use a result set from multiple threads. JDBC drivers are required to be thread-safe, but interleaved access on a result set will just lead to race conditions and undefined behaviour in your code (eg two threads calling `next()` and getting a value), because the driver may be threadsafe, **your** actions on it won't be without proper synchronization, which will just lead to serialized access which means you could just as well do everything on a single thread. I'm intentionally posting this in a comment ,because your real problem is far simpler (missing `where` clause).

Comment: Read the answer that you got. Your original code tells us that the account number is a string, and that you're looking for rows where the account number *contains* the substring `"2195281819521610731"`. The updated code tries to pass a number instead of a string, and gets the rows where the account number is *equal* to the giant number passed. Use the correct data type, and use the correct comparison operator.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just add the condition to your query?

instead of

```
   select account_number,flag,flag2,flag3,flag4,flag5,flag6,flag7,amount from transaction_p2
```

do

```
  select account_number,flag,flag2,flag3,flag4,flag5,flag6,flag7,amount from transaction_p2 where account_number like '%2195281819521610731%'
```

the last part (`where account_number like '%...%'`) will tell SQL to only include the results whose `account_number` contains the given string.

Comment: It should be `where account_number like...`

Comment: I assume you meant to use normal double quotes (") instead of the fancy quotes (“ and ”)